Как с помощью тернарного оператора вывести в консоль сообщение и присвоить значение?
int xxx = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())) == 5 ? Console.WriteLine("win") & 5: Console.WriteLine("loss") & 0;
}

Что мне нужно:
Чтобы после ввода цифры, она сравнивалась с цифрой 5,и в случае если число нужное, вывелось сообщение и присвоилось переменной 5,а в противном случае сообщение и присвоилось 0;

Это можно сделать с помощью одного тернар-оператора, но это будет выглядеть криво и больше, чем по-обычному? Зачем оно вам?

Просто хотел узнать как с помощью тернарногого и присвоить и вывести, подскажите пж

Так выглядит то, что вы хотите. Выглядит как полноценный костыл. Не советую так писать.

@eccs0103, можно ответом оформить, и написать почему не советуете, будет полезно

@Dev18 добавьте лучше к себе. Так как я ещё должен написать, как будет правильно, а на этот вопрос вы уже ответили.

@eccs0103, Не советую так писать - я не знаю почему))) уверенна. у вас есть хорошее объяснение

@Dev18 так вы же написали это не является хорошей практикой, так как усложняет понимание кода

Кстати, если иметь friendly код для своих коллег, то писать надо прям чисто явно: считываем данные в переменную. Далее внизу через обычный if пишем "Если значение не равно MY_EXPECTED_VALUE, тогда throw UserException(...)" а ноль вообще не должно быть.... либо ноль тоже должен лежать в константе с ГОВОРЯЩИМ НАИМЕНОВАНИЕМ и присваивать туда.... в общем суть: код должен быть легко читаем и понятен... а все магии 5,0 - это плохо... за лёгкий читаемый код программисты скажут спасибо. За сжатый и нечитабельный - обматерят и занесут в чёрный список))

@eccs0103, вы только поэтому не советуете?

@Dev18 а этого мало? Представьте, что вам дают код на исправление в 1000 строк в таком виде. У меня было такое на практике.

@eccs0103, но это не имеет отношение к вопросу. Мы же не технику и чистый код обсуждаем, а отвечаем на вопрос ТС (те условно идёт ответ, что вот так можно, но.... И по пунктам пройтись почему не надо

@Dev18, я отвечаю исключительно технически корректным кодом. Если по каким-либо причинам это невозможно, то я не оставляю ответ, как в данном случае.

Тернарный оператор возвращает значение по-моему, но он не позволит выполнять несколько операций, таких как И вывод в консоль И присваивание значения переменной одновременно
Хотя технически это можно сделать ---смотрите ответ
@eccs0103 в комментариях, это не является хорошей практикой, так как усложняет понимание кода
В тернарном операторе лучше оставить только присваивание значения, а вывод сообщений сделать до или после него
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int xxx = input == 5 ? 5 : 0;
Console.WriteLine(xxx == 5 ? "win" : "loss");

вот так тоже можно
 int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 int xxx = input == 5 ? PrintAndReturn("win", 5) : PrintAndReturn("loss", 0);

 int PrintAndReturn(string message, int value)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(message);
     return value;
 }

